# VBA For Each worksheet only working on first sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a workbook with 17 sheets and each one has a product list that will change from month to month. If a product has errors, it shows up as CMB in the values but the product is still there. I was to delete the product rows. This code works on a sheet by sheet basis, but once I try to loop it, it does not work.

```
Sub wsLoop()
Dim ws as Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
'Seeing if there are new products added to list
countcells = Range(Range("F8").End(xlDown).Offset(, -4), Range("A8").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
'if no products added, then see if there in CMB in any row and delete that row
If countcells = 1 Then
If Not Range("E:E").Find("CMB") Is Nothing Then

Range(Range("E:E").Find("CMB"), Range("E8").End(xlDown)).Rows.EntireRow.Delete

End If
End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually get the range of the current worksheet. E.g.,

```
countcells = ws.Range(ws.Range("F8").End(xlDown).Offset(, -4), ws.Range("A8").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

Otherwise, you will always be just grabbing ranges off the currently selected worksheet (which will generally be the first worksheet).

Note that you will need to repeat this for all instances of `Range`.

---

By the way, one thing you can do to make this easier is to use `With`:

```
With ws
    countcells = .Range(.Range("F8").End(xlDown).Offset(, -4), .Range("A8").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    'repeat for all lines
End With
```

`With` eliminates the need to repeat the name of the object over and over. You just type `.property`, and it automatically knows you mean `ws.property`.

Comment: OP needs to add the `ws.` to all `Range(..`s not just that one line.

Comment: Thanks, @ScottCraner. Added a bit more content to hopefully clarify.

Comment: 'If countcells > 2 Then
   
    .Range("F8").End(xlDown).Offset(, -4).Resize(, 6).Copy
    .Range(.Range("F8").End(xlDown).Offset(1, -4), .Range("B8").End(xlDown).Offset(, 5)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    
    .Range("F8").End(xlDown).Resize(, 2).AutoFill Destination:=.Range("F8").End(xlDown).Resize(countcells, 2), Type:=xlFillDefault'
    
    End If' This is another part of my code with in the with ws. It is saying there is an application defined or object defined error. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: sorry i do not know how to make it easier to read through the comments

Comment: Try using "back tick" (`) to enclose any code in your comments.

Comment: `If countcells > 2 Then
   
    .Range("F8").End(xlDown).Offset(, -4).Resize(, 6).Copy
    .Range(.Range("F8").End(xlDown).Offset(1, -4), .Range("B8").End(xlDown).Offset(, 5)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    
    .Range("F8").End(xlDown).Resize(, 2).AutoFill Destination:=.Range("F8").End(xlDown).Resize(countcells, 2), Type:=xlFillDefault
    
    End If`

Comment: As for the error, do you still get it if you move the code outside the `With` block (and remove the `.` before each `Range`)?

Comment: No i do not. It works outside the with block. It is highlighting the format paste line of code

Comment: OK, I would recommend you try to break that long statement into pieces. Specifically, try setting some of the ranges to variables, such as `Dim source as Range`. `Set source = .Range("F8").End(xlDown).Offset(, -4).Resize(, 6)`. This will allow you to see more easily which part of the statement is failing.